# fixed background image causing slow scroll in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

A fixed background image is causing my Chrome browser to lag severely when scrolling over the fixed background image. I checked in Mozilla and did not have this issue.

While Googling the issue I found that this has been a known problem for some time now. What is a good work-around for getting a fixed background image to work across the board?

Comment: You can try implementing your own scroll in order to "speed up" the scrolling with SmoothScroll.js (https://gist.github.com/galambalazs/6477177) . That might counteract the lag.If you can put up a working gist that demonstrates the problem it would help myself and others test any proposed solutions like this.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to minimize the image file. Also, instead of linking, you may try to embed the image using `Base64` encoding (as an example, you may refer to the actual website using `Base64` without any scrolling problem: http://alexanderbell.us/Quiz/) Hope this may help.

Comment: I have already compressed my background image jpg's. That was the first thing I thought to try. I did manage to reduce the original file sizes by 75%, however this did not improve scrolling performance.

Comment: Try Base64 encoding. Also, would you please post the link to the problematic website, so we would be able to analyze the problem. Otherwise, this question would be closed because it's impossible for us to reproduce/analyze the issue.

Comment: In my case changing background-image dimensions to smaller fixed the issue.